# Questions relevant to "Table per concrete class mapping" in hibernate technique

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, joined-subclass, union-subclass

Am trying to understand inheritance types with hibernate.

when i look document there is "Table per concrete class" topic using union-subclass technique.  Regarding this I am having some questions,

**1). Why we need union-subclass mapping? 

2). When will we implement union-subclass? 

3). Why we can not use id generator for union-subclass? 

4). What are the advantages over joined-subclass?**

Comment: This smells like a homework question. If so, that should be mentioned. Also, probably belongs on Programmer's SE, not SO.